# JS - Set a global variable, inside of an anonymous function?

Tags: javascript, ajax, anonymous-function

This is a part of script used to pull list items from SharePoint 2013. I'm trying to test two different lists which is why I have two different anonymous functions. I cannot seem to figure out how to set the **pLead** variable in the first function to use in the second function. It always does the if statement in the second function because it thinks the string is empty. Why is it like this? I cannot seem to get my head around it, I'm talking about this:

```
var pLead = "";

$(function() {

    $.ajax({
            url: "__URL__",
            headers: {"Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"}, 
            type: "GET", 
            cache: false,      

    }).success(function (data) {
        $.each(data.d.results, function(key, value) {
        pLead = "TESSTT";
        }); 
    });
});

$(function() {

    $.ajax({
            //DTIM Projects page
            url: "__URL__",
            headers: {"Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"}, 
            type: "GET", 
            cache: false,      

    }).success(function (data) {
        $.each(data.d.results, function(key, value) {
            if (pLead.length === 0) { $("#ProjectLead").html(value.PL); }
            else { $("#ProjectLead").html(pLead); }
        }); 
    });
});
```

Comment: AJAX is asynchronous. You need to use promises.

Comment: Or callbacks, or whatever trick you'd like to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its a good idea to name your functions even if you just use it for debugging. If the the second function is supposed to be called when the first function completes you don't need the pLead variable, just name your second function and call it from the success or done handler of the first function.

```
  function firstFunction() {
   $.ajax({ ... }).done(secondFunction);
}
```

Comment: ... and *name* those functions, and place them in the source-code, so that it is *instantly obvious* that the two belong together.  Liberally add comments to point out what you are doing and why.